# Text File, MongoDB or JSON?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, discord.py, bots

So, I’m learning python and discord.py, and out of a bot with 500 lines of code, I only asked help with one item. The rest, I’ve been researching myself and trial and error. I’m currently at a cross roads, and would like some advice which route to take. I’m not looking to ask how, I’ll figure that on my own ( hopefully ).

So, I have a bot running on my Windows PC, only running on a single server, which is my own. The bot returns an embedded message with a list of inactive users, which is based on a series of roles. After a few nested IF statements, it adds the field with person.mention. Then posts the list to a specific channel, mentioning them all.

As per rules, they have 48 hours to improve their activity, which will modify their roles.

So, while the first command works like a charm, I’m looking to create a second command that goes through the list of users from the previous “audit” ( typically about 15-30 people ) check them to see if their activity has improved ( if set of roles exist ) and report back in a staff channel “Members out of compliance, and subject to removal:” then the list of saved users wiped for the next audit. ( twice a month )

To do this, I need to research how, but for the sake of saving me time, I’m asking which route should I investigate and why? Text File? DB? Or JSON?

I appreciate everyone’s input.

Comment: Difficult to give advice for such a vague description. But if it only runs on a single host, I'd go with JSON, as you can very easily do `with open("filename", "w") as file: json.dump(users_dict_or_list, file)` and `with open("filename") as file: users = json.read(file)`. Seems like the least amount of hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd normally suggest using a small database (like sqlite) for small bots, but if you're new to python you shouldn't learn SQL. I guess using a `JSON` file works, though using them as a database is not a great idea, it's mostly used as a config file. A few downsides of using `JSON` files are:

- It's a file-based data storage, which makes it vulnerable to race conditions.
- You'll need to implement your own synchronization primitives to avoid corrupting data.
- If you're not careful, you could accidentally wipe your entire `JSON` file.

Another alternative to `JSON` files are `yaml` or `toml` files, but the downsides are the same.

---

Using databases:

If you want to learn SQL (there are good, free, easy to follow sources out there like [sqlbolt](https://sqlbolt.com/)) the advantages are:

- Databases organize your data into tables, and are fast at inserting, retrieving, and removing records.
- You can impose uniqueness constraints to ensure against duplication.
- The Python libraries enforce synchronization for you.
- The query language is intuitive, you can get running with simple queries in just a few hours!

MongoDB is an excellent choice for a database, I haven't personally used it but it's a good non-relational database (doesn't use SQL).

*PS: Don't even think about using `txt` files as a database, that's a bad, bad, bad idea.*